# Way to remotely update Jenkins "System Message" string?

Tags: jenkins

Is there a way to remotely insert/update the Jenkins "System Message" (instance description that is displayed across the top of the screen)?

We deploy our Jenkins Jobs via API and would like to be able to tell what versions of jobs were deployed at a glance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no API for modifying the system message. This value can only be modified by the [config window](https://github.com/jenkinsci/jenkins/blob/22aa2e6e766074d11249893e3f35e0b99e20d3d0/core/src/main/resources/jenkins/model/Jenkins/configure.jelly), as of jenkins-2.143.

```
<f:entry title="${%System Message}" help="/help/system-config/systemMessage.html">
        <f:textarea name="system_message" value="${it.systemMessage}"
                    codemirror-mode="${app.markupFormatter.codeMirrorMode}" codemirror-config="${app.markupFormatter.codeMirrorConfig}" previewEndpoint="/markupFormatter/previewDescription"/>
</f:entry>
```

However, you  can set the description entry for the main page (or any page) with the `submitDescription` API. The description entry is right below the system message field on the main page, so if you leave system message empty, you can use the description field as a pseudo system message.

This is a sample using curl. `submitDescription` is available with the XML, python and JSON API as well.

```
user=my_user
password=12345678
description="this is a description"
jenkins_url="my_server"

curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD --data-urlencode "description=$description" \
    --data-urlencode "Submit=Submit" \
    "$jenkins_url/submitDescription"
```

You can also use it for a job, or job number description if you use the following url instead:

```
"$jenkins_url/job/$job/submitDescription
"$jenkins_url/job/$job/$build_number/submitDescription
```

Comment: is there a way to include a tag in this curl? for example `<h1>Test Jenkins title</h1>`

Comment: better example: `<h1 style="color:#1a1aff;font-size:"5";">FOSS STAGING JENKINS</h1>`

Answer (score 3):

I also found a solution involving using a curl against the Script API to run a Groovy script to write directly to the SystemMessage:

curl:

```
user=my_user
password=12345678
jenkins_url="my_server"

curl -u $USER:$PASSWORD -d "script=$(cat /tmp/script.groovy)" \
"$jenkins_url/script"
```

Groovy Script (`/tmp/script.groovy`):

```
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
Jenkins j = Jenkins.instance
def now = new Date()
String system_message = ('System Header Message')

j.systemMessage = system_message
```

Comment: will it also accept tag? for example `<h1>Test Jenkins title</h1>` from the UI it does works

Comment: better example: `<h1 style="color:#1a1aff;font-size:"5";">FOSS STAGING JENKINS</h1>`